# Beginner FMDB iOS Database, Table Creation

Tags: ios, database, sqlite, fmdb

How would you create a database file in an iOS app? I am using FMDB in Xcode (Swift) and I have created functions to execute queries here:

```
func query()
{
    let DB = FMDatabase(path: dbFilePath as String)
    if DB.open()
    {
        let querySQL = "SELECT * FROM SHOPS"
        let results:FMResultSet? = DB.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
        print(querySQL)
        DB.close()
        print(results)
    }
    else
    {
        print("Error: \(DB.lastErrorMessage())")
    }
}
```

My create database function needs help as in the FMDB documentation states: *An FMDatabase is created with a path to a SQLite database file. This path can be one of these three: 
A file system path. The file does not have to exist on disk. If it does not exist, it is created for you.* But where can I obtain the file path to the database file?

I also have a question for how to continue the create table function:

```
   func create()
    {
    let createString = "CREATE TABLE Shops(id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, name char(255);)"
    }
```

Do I use executeUpdate? Please provide concise and clear answer as I am a beginner if it is not too time consuming for you. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 8.0 Swift 3.0 version**

In Your **Appdelegate.swift** Copy the below code

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool
    {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        Util.copyFile("<yourDatabaseName>.sqlite") 
        getDocDir()
        return true
    }

func getDocDir() -> String
    {
        print(NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0])
        return NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    }
```

And then Run Xcode: Short cut key: build (Cmd + B) -> Run(Cmd + R)

> Check console of Xcode get a path like below example:

Sample image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH0AV.png

Copy the path from:

```
/users//tooti/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/..../data/Containers/Data/Application/.../Documents/
```

-> Open Finder-> Go -> Go to folder and paste the path copied from above

Sample image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DmzH8.png

-> then click Enter. That's it done. You will find a **.sqlite** file

- Also you can open your database file with SQLite manager/Firefox browser/DBManagerExtension tool.